# Parse the coordinates of placemarks in a kml file using C#

Tags: kml, android-maps-v2

I have the following kml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.x">
   <Placemark>
   <name>My Home</name>
   <description>Here is the place where I live</description>
   <Point>
    <coordinates>-122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251,0</coordinates>
   </Point>
</Placemark>
```

I would like to parse the longitude and latitude of the placemarks in the above file.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain...   I spent quite a while implementing this for something I was working on.  Here is a quick example of parsing Latitude and Longitude values from a .kml file:

Start with a place to store the Latitude and Longitude values:

```
public class Location
    {
        public float Latitude { get; set; }
        public float Longitude { get; set; }
    }
```

Then get the stream from your .kml file (in my case, I use the same .kml file all the time and have it in my project with its build action set to 'Embedded Resource' :

```
Stream stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.Filename.kml");
List<Location> locations = ParseLocations(stream);
```

Here is the implementation for ParseLocations:

```
public static List<Location> ParseLocations(Stream stream)
{
    List<Location> locationList = new List<Location>();
    var doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
    XNamespace ns = "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1";
    var result = doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "Placemark");
    foreach (XElement xmlTempleInfo in result)
    {
        var point = xmlTempleInfo.Element(ns + "Point");
        string[] coordinates = point.Element(ns + "coordinates").Value.Split(",".ToCharArray());

        locationList.Add(new Location()
        {
           Latitude = float.Parse(coordinates[1])
           Longitude = float.Parse(coordinates[0]),
        });
    }

    return locationList;
}
```